# Unity Scene does not load properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

Last night I finished up on unity and saved my project and scene before closing unity.

This morning when I loaded up unity My Hierarchy, scene and game view are all empty, I don't even have a main camera. This has happened before so I closed off unity (Without Saving or anything) and opened it through the scene file, to my surprise again it does not work, Thinking it must have just not loaded the scene again I tried loading the scene in unity, again no result, now I've spent the last 2 hours browsing the internet trying to find the solution to the problem.

A few common answers I've seen for this problem that do not work for me:

Unity is not opening a new scene, it says at the top it is currently in the scene I want.

Pressing F does not fix anything since there is nothing in the hierarchy in the first place.

Also:

The project is saved in DropBox.

All the assets say they were last updated when I last saved and closed Unity.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's weird. Try creating another simple project and simple scene. Save them, restart unity/pc/mac, now try opening the project. What happens?

Comment: @ImtiajAhmed The new project re-opens fine and everything loads, but when i try and open the project i was having difficulties with it still does not load properly, I'm slightly worried that the file has corrupted, I can role back the file in dropbox, I'm wondering at this point if thats the best idea

Comment: I think so. The file is corrupted.

Comment: I suggest you use git, is easier to rollback and see the changes on your files.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, Unity and Dropbox don't really get along, as one may lock files the other one wants to read/write, and that means sometimes files not saved properly.

If you want to share projects or just have an online backup, prefer other tools that don't scan the folder all the time, like Git.

Comment: If such a tool is not possible, you should simply work on a separate copy  and move it into whatever backup utility you're using once you're done working. Protip: you never need to backup the Library directory. That is generated by Unity every time it runs. It might increase your startup time, but it will save on space and prevent some other weird issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. open run prompt (windows+R)
2. %AppData% --> "Roaming" folder will open.
3. Search for Unity and delete this folder.
4. Go up one folder up (AppData) and do the same to Local/Unity and LocalLow/Unity